Surges observed at the output of the LT3021 regulator

we are using the LT3021 regulator to generate the gate voltage for the power amplifier. The VG(PA) shutdown control signal is provided by a microcontroller. The VR1 potentiometer is used to set the gate voltage according to the IDQ and this done only when VG(PA) goes HIGH. When the VG(PA) signal is LOW it sets to pinch-off voltage that is 0V for the power amplifier.
The issue is that when the card is initially powered on, there is a surge at the output VG_REF_PA. The results attached below show that when the power is initially turned on, a surge of 712.92 mV appears at the output. Although the SHDN is initially set to LOW in the software program, which prevents any surge at the SHDN signal, a surge still occurs at the output. These results were observed after multiple power on/off cycles.


Have you also monitored the SHDN pin during startup/power up? What is the sequence of the different power rails? VCC5V0 and and power for the MCU?

@Tyassin Yes! there is no surge on SHDN pin at start-up, surge is observed at output. the power supply to the MCU is 3.3V which is being generated from a regulator whose input is VCC5V0. So the sequence is, first LT3021 is powered up. Later the MCU is powered up.

Ok. Is there a reason why the spikes seems periodic? Is it something from your turn on sequence?

there is no sequence, we just powered on and off multiple times. when ever it is powered on the spikes are coming

Hi; I have gone through the datasheet for the device and I noticed that they recommend a minimum of 3.3uF on at the output of the regulator. Some types of LDO can be very sensitive to output capacitance and the ESR of these and the LDO can become unstable if this is not sufficient.
You also have to consider the derating of ceramic capacitors, if it is these that are used.  A 3.3uF capacitor will not be 3.3uF as soon as DC voltage is applied to it, you should check the datasheet.
Is the output of LTLT3021 stable when it is running?

@Tyassin  Ya! LT3021 is stable while running, only at the power ON time and also when enable the SHDN signal we observed a spike of 250mV.
We even tried by increasing the output capacitors, even though the spikes are continued.

Ok do you also see the behavior if everything is started up and you enable and disable the LT3021 with the MCU?

Is VG(PA) connected directly to a MCU pin?

Ya VG(PA) is directly connected to MCU pin

Not sure whats going on. Maybe also some other things with your board. But as a last thing try and ground the SHDN pin with a zero ohm resistor. Although you should be careful not to drive the MCU pin, maybe set it as an input or high impedance state.

Even though spikes are generated if the SHDN pi is connected to input supply or Ground. We also tried by changing multiple capacitance at the input side and also output. the spikes were not dependent upon the capacitance. we are not able to determine why these spikes are produced.
